# Fromatting double value to 2 decimals

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to format my double value to 2 decimals and then make it "text to speech".
this is my code:

```
mares = mass * acc;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
df.format(mares);
String mare = String.format("The force is %f", df);
home.speak(mare,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

but it crashes, i don't know why, i put 5 and 6 and it should multiply them and give me 30.00 or something like that.
when i remove DecimalFormat the result is 30.00000000000000, i just don't like it, too many zeros.
can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DecimalFormat` is returning the formatted string, but you are ignoring it, and passing it as an argument to `String.format`, which certainly isn't right.

Assign the return of `df.format` to a string for further reference:

```
String mare = df.format(mares);
```

Or pass the numeric value directly to `String.format`, with the appropriate format precision specified:

```
String mare = String.format("The force is %.2f", mares);
```